# Input fields (made using wtforms) break after adding jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I'm creating a simple flask web app, that is essentially a series of input forms. I was successfully able to make a test form using wtforms with the following code:

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField, validators, IntegerField, FileField, SelectMultipleField

class FooInputs(Form):
    foo = StringField('Foo', default='bar')
    jazz = SelectMultipleField('Jazz', choice=[(...
```

rendered in this template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
</head>

<body>
  <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <dl>
      {% for FIELD in FIELDS %}
        {{ render_field(form[FIELD]) }}
      {% endfor %}
    </dl>
    <p><input type=submit value=Next>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

where `_formhelpers.html` can be found in the Flask documentation here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/wtforms/. (`FIELDS` is a list of field names passed in via the flask handler)

I have since been trying to add the functionality that when a comma is entered into an input field, the comma is suppressed, and instead an additional input field pops up. I was able to make this work on a test html that didn't use jinja2 or wtforms, using this jQuery script:

```
$(":input").live("keydown", function() {
    if (event.which===188) {
        $(this).parent().prepend($(this).clone());
        $(this).prev().focus();
        return false
    }
});
```

However, when I introduce this script into my form as shown here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method=post enctype>
    <dl>
      {% for FIELD in FIELDS %}
        {{ render_field(form[FIELD]) }}
      {% endfor %}
    </dl>
    <p><input type=submit value=Next>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/variable_form.js">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

it all seems to work except for one major problem, no characters ever appear in the form's input fields. I can type a comma, and a new field appears, but I am never able to type into any of the input fields on the form.

I suspect this has to do with wtforms' underlying javascript, but I'm unsure as to how to approach this problem. I have considered dropping the use of wtforms, but I do like its functionality, and would prefer to hold onto what I have already developed.

I am totally new to web development, so I may have missed something obvious. Let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: wtforms doesn't come with any javascript natively. The validation is done serverside in python

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to return `true` for the event listener as a default (eg not a comma). In your example code, it would look like:

```
$(":input").live("keydown", function() {
    if (event.which===188) {
        $(this).parent().prepend($(this).clone());
        $(this).prev().focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

The underlying idea being that you are capturing all "keydown" events in the input, but in your original code, it only returns a value if the keydown event is a comma, with all other keydown events having nothing returned by that event listener function.